# What is difference compiling PyModuleDef using gcc and Visual Studio

Tags: c++, python-3.x

I am working on a project and I have the following code...

```
static PyMethodDef MyModule_methods[] = {
    { "loadFunc", loadFunc, METH_VARARGS, "Load Function" },
    { NULL, NULL, 0, NULL }        /* Sentinel */
};

static struct PyModuleDef MyModule_module = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "MyModule",
    "My Module", 
    -1,       
    MyModule_methods
};
```

It seems to compile fine for my co-worker on visual studio, however, when I try compiling I get the error....

```
MyModule.cpp:500:8: error: ‘PyModuleDef’ does not name a type
  static PyModuleDef MyModule_module = {
```

Can anyone see what I am missing?

Comment: You're missing an include that defines what a `PyModuleDef` is.

Comment: No I have it just did not include it I think it comes from `#include <Python.h>` rt?

Comment: Ahhh maybe I figured it out, I think I am using python 2.7 with 3.4 headers checking it out now

Comment: Nope looks like it is still there for 2.7 `$ find /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/ -name Python.h
/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/usr/include/python2.7/Python.h`

Comment: Does visual studio offer a way to see the preprocessor output? That often gives useful hints

Comment: The resource that has VS is out of office so it would take some time

Comment: Looks like it was Python2.7 Python.h I change my version to 3.x and I get a bit farther.